# Openstack installation error on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, openstack

I'm getting the following error while installing Openstack on Ubuntu 16.04.7. Can someone please help.[openstack-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ORE.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of text (or links to images of text). Include the error you are asking about in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: if you're using `devstack` for the install please post your `local.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing a version of OpenStack that is no longer supported on Ubuntu 16.04. You either need to upgrade to 20.04 or 18.04.

An alternative would be to try to install an older version of OpenStack that supports Ubuntu 16.04 by changing the branch you use for Devstack.

> git checkout stable/rocky